# Using plotly inside an rmarkdown notebook (html notebook) outside of Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, r-plotly, ggplotly

Is it possible to use the [`html_notebook` aka `r notebook`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) format with `plotly`?

When I use the rmarkdown file (named `temp.Rmd`) shown below, I can `knit to HTML` and everything works -- that is, I can view a proper `temp.html` file. However, when I use the `Preview Notebook` button within `RStudio` which opens a preview pane or if I view the `temp.nb.html` file, I am missing the `plotly` output.

**temp.Rmd**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

Some text here.

```{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p, width = 500, height = 500)

mtcars
```

More text here.
````

**Session Info**

```
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.2.593)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2018-05-01      

 ggplot2     * 2.2.1.9000 2018-04-27 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@1d537ce)
 plotly      * 4.7.1.9000 2018-04-27 Github (ropensci/plotly@38f447f)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `ggplotly(p, width = 500, height = 500)` in its code chunk? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @hpesoj626 yes, it's in there -- see example -- still if I do `Preview` I only see the `plotly` output in the `Viewer` pane, not in the generated `Preview` pop-up nor the `temp.nb.html` file.

Comment: I meant "put `ggplotly(p, width = 500, height = 500)` in its own code chunk.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Same result, only shows up in the `Viewer` pane - does not populate below the chunk nor the `.nb.html` file.